# Reproducible method to generate an anonymous identifier?

Tags: privacy, identification

I've been working on a web application that needs to provide a way to create an **anonymous identifier** that can be used to identify one or more rows in a database that refer to a person who has called into a switchboard (let's call them a "**client**") *without actually storing any identifiable information* about that **client**. The **switchboard operator** should be able to:

1. ask a few questions of the **client** that (*ideally*) only the client can answer
2. enter their responses into an ephemeral online "calculator" form that *doesn't save/submit the data*
3. receive an **anonymous identifier** from that form
4. enter that **anonymous identifier** into the the app that will be used to handle the **client**'s request (let's call that the **CRM**)

Notably:

- *personally identifiable information* must *never* be stored in the **CRM**
- the same questions are asked of every **client**
- if the same **client** calls again one year later—and *answers the same questions*—a different **switchboard operator** would get the same **anonymous identifier** in response, and would see the entries about that **client** entered into the **CRM** by other operators into the who have answered calls from that same **client** in the past
- the **client** is ***never asked to remember an identifier, password, or other secret***

For example, John Doe calls the switchboard, and is asked to provide their:

- First and Last name
- DOB
- City of birth

In my prototype: the name is processed with a simple *Soundex*-like algorithm (to avoid spelling errors) and returns a number; the date of birth returns a number a the number of days since an arbitrary epoch; and the city of birth returns a *Where on Earth Identifier*. These are then concatenated, salted, and hashed to return an anonymous identifier (e.g. `3:L3kmw:Ly`, using SSDEEP so that the **switchboard operator** doesn't have to type many characters into the **CRM**), though the hashing algorithm isn't important). The form used to generate the **anonymous identifier** calculates everything in the browser, and doesn't store/save/submit anything.

Is there a better approach to *reproducibly* generate an **anonymous identifier**? Are there better questions/procedures to reduce the risk of social engineering by others who might wish to gain information about a **client**?

Interested in all ideas, critiques, etc.. Will edit with changes as requested.

Comment: What happens when there's a typo in the names (last names and cities can be tricky) typed by the operator (like "John" and "john")? This is very frequent. What happens when the client does not want to disclose personally identifiable information, like his date of birth, and gives a fake one instead if forced to do it (a different one each time)?

Comment: What you suggest doing is fingerprinting the users. This is covered by the GDPR: [GDPR and Browser Fingerprinting](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2018/06/gdpr-and-browser-fingerprinting-how-it-changes-game-sneakiest-web-trackers) The "anonymous" identifier remains identifier, so you will need the _informed and unambiguous_ agreement from the client to process it.

Comment: This is for a U.S.-only system in the social service sector that currently collects PII from callers who would be compliant with the questions. While I used the word "CRM" to describe the database, it's more of a call journal. No contact information would be stored, just notes on the content of the call, and this information is stored with the consent of the caller.  Also, Soundex accounts for most of the typos, and the U.S. postal code is looked up from the city of birth.